# HTML Download Counter

Tags: download, counter

On my website I have a download, but I want it to display the number of downloads next to the download Button. I have found websites that do It for you, but It gives me an HTML link instead of a button.

A bit like the counter here www.minecraft.net
My Site www.Go-Create.Net/game

Thanks! : )

Answer (score 0):

Added Some JavaScript to log how many times the link is clicked. That is saved into a .txt file which is then displayed where ever I want.